# How to make table in html?

Tags: html, html-table

I want to create a table in html and I mantion my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Table</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

This is my expected output:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

Comment: Have ypou even tried searching online?  The very first results for "HTML table" give examples for exactly what you want: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  People are willing to help you only if you take your time and make the effort of figuring out how to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for make table,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Table</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Column A</th>
          <th>Column B</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 1</td>
          <td>Cell 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell 3</td>
          <td>Cell 4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Copy This and Run This in Your HTML File
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Table</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
        <th>Column A</th>
        <th>Column B</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can learn how to create html table [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

But I'll leave this sample so you can move on.

```css
table{
    width: 70%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
th{
    background-color: hsl(210,8%,95%);
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column A</th>
            <th>Column B</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell 1</td>
            <td>Cell 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell 3</td>
            <td>Cell 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```